# How to get common style for FF and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have something like `<b> sample text <b>` renders diffently in IE and FF

In **IE** like `<Strong>sample text</Strong>`

In **FF** something like `<font style="font:bold">Sample Text</Font>`

how to get common style or convert any one of it to another

Thanks

Comment: Definitely gonna need a link, or some code, or something.

Comment: @diEcho Where did those edits come from? If that's the actual problem that @user634036 is experiencing, awesome. I just don't know how you figured it out.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc just try to edit the question, you will find where is the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS to style your page.

```
strong {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
     <span style="font-weight:bold"> sample text </span>
```

also you can use css shorthand like

```
           <span style="font:bold 13px arial;"> sample text </span>
```

**Note:** `<font>` has been deprecated

Reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-style

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font

Answer (score 0):

If you need to simply differentiate the CSS inclusion you can use the IE conditions in HTML :

```
<![if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]>
```

and for all the other cases

```
<![if !IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
<![endif]>
```

If you need something more specific you will have to use some hacks, but it's not recommended at all